# Are % comments passed on to the PDF-file upon *.tex compilation?

Tags: pdf, compiling, comments

Are % comments passed on to the PDF-file upon *.tex compilation? Can they be found/recovered in the PDF code?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\title{\textbf{Hello World !}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1] Some more text\footnote{https://lipsum.info/}.

% Highly fishy, confidential, controversial, politically incorrect, top-secret, this should never be published or leaked (nor should have been typed or typeset in the first place): bla bla bla \ldots

\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like [Are comments safely hidden once the document is compiled?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57966/are-comments-safely-hidden-once-the-document-is-compiled) to me

Comment: yep, just marked it as duplicate myself :)

Comment: OK, in that case I'll close straight-away :-)