# How to put on and off comments while publishing latex documents into PDF

Tags: pdftex, pdf, comments

I created a file using TeXstudio, I have lots of comments in the document. I want publish the document one version with the comments and the other without it. Is three a way to put on and off comments when publishing a PDF file in LaTEX? Will be of great help if some one can help me on this.

P.S I am not sure where to tag since I am a new user of latex and also this forum

Comment: By comments are you referring to having commented your code using `%`? If that's the case, publishing to a PDF is completely independent of your comments. That is, they won't make it into the output PDF file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Are comments safely hidden once the document is compiled?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57966/5764)

Comment: The _fixme_ package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixme?lang=en is a really good way to do this.

Comment: @Werner seems to have answered your question. I will just add that if there is material you want to show sometimes but not always you can use the `comment1 package (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @EthanBolker your response is much more informative. appreciate it

Comment: And the comment environment (`\begin{comment} ... \end{comment}`can't be intended, beginning and end have to be first in a new line.